# How do I select a theme and change theme configuration from moodle config.php file?

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

I want to select a theme by setting `$CFG->` value in `config.php`. How can I do that?
Also, I want to change the brand colour in the theme by accessing `theme_moove | brandcolor` in the `config.php` file.

[image]

Currently, I'm able to set other values in `config.php` like the following.

```
$CFG->enablemobilewebservice = true;

$CFG->passwordpolicy = false;

$CFG->updateautocheck = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the answer to the question from the Moodle forum by Leon Stringer. So sharing it here, because someone might find it useful in the SO community.

Core settings can be set by setting the corresponding `$CFG` property as you have stated, so the theme can be set with:

```
$CFG->theme = 'moove';
```

Plugin settings (a theme is a plugin) are set with `$CFG->forced_plugin_settings`. This is described in config-dist.php under "8. FORCED SETTINGS". E.g. to set `theme_moove | brandcolor`:

```
$CFG->forced_plugin_settings = array('theme_moove'  => array('brandcolor' => '#022B78'));
```